# JavaScript/JQuery - for loop to pull items from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, for-loop

I am trying to pull each element 'one by one' from two separate HTML lists and print each element after the other. If that doesn't make sense, here is some pseudo-code to better explain what I am trying to accomplish.

```
$('#tracktitle').append("<li class='titlelist'><a href='" + track.permalink_url + "' target='_blank'>" + track.title +"</a><br></li>")
  $('#trackimage').append("<li class='imagelist'><a href='" + track.permalink_url + "' target='_blank'><img src='" + track.artwork_url + "' /></a></li>");

for(var i =0;i<7;i++){
  // print 1st tracktitle
  // print 1st image
  // print 2nd tracktitle
  // 2nd image ... etc
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? Do you want to create a string, append some HTML, log to the console, etc?

Comment: do you have an array of track objects

Comment: `from two html lists`...what do they look like? Question not making sense without filling in some blanks. Non working code is not a good substitute for a good explanation

Comment: whatever data ur having using .each on that and adhere the append code inside with respective data using jquery will do..

Comment: @Cuberto I suppose I am trying to append to the HTML. from what I hear using document.write isn't very good practice. but whatever i can do to print 1 element after the next would make me very happy

Comment: @codebreaker that sounds like exactly what I am looking for. I am doing some research on using .each but i'm not exactly sure how I can apply it to this. any chance you could give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use for loop do this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $('#tracktitle').find('li:eq(' + i + ')'); // gives you the li tracktitle element as per index
    $('#trackimage').find('li:eq(' + i + ')'); // gives you the li trackimage element as per index
}
```

To get the text and image use

```
$('#tracktitle').find('li:eq(' + i + ')').find('a').text();
$('#trackimage').find('li:eq(' + i + ')').find('a').html()
```

You can also use [jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) if you want to navigate for elements

```
$('#tracktitle').find('li.titlelist').each(function () {
   $(this) // gives you li element
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/FVTUN/3/

Comment: that seems very close to what i am looking for. but it still seems to print all 'tracktitle' elements and then all 'trackimage' elements. I am trying to get it to print tracktitle1 and trackimage1, followed by tracktitle2 and trackimage2, etc.